# query sql in controller laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5.5

Error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '&& `product_price` > ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `table_products` where && `product_price` > 0)

my code:

```
public function faq(Request $request) {

    $pro = Product::all();
    $p_1  = Product::where('product_price', '>', 0,'&&', 'product_price','<', 250)->get();
    return view('fontend.errors.faq', compact('pro', 'p_1'));
}
```

Comment: what's your code on HomeController.php line 131?

Comment: thank you, bug in this old post I had fixed. Can you help me query mysql

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.

Comment: ok i had fixed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `where()` to your query to apply filter

```
$p_1  = Product::where('product_price', '>', 0)
               ->where('product_price','<', 250)
               ->get();
```

this will produce a query like

```
select * from table_products where product_price > 0 and product_price < 250
```

or you could use [`->whereBetween()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

```
$p_1  = Product::whereBetween('product_price', [0, 250])
               ->get();
```